# sqlserver fetch from multitable

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables
user table (to store user info)
module table (stores info about platforms)
permission table (where user id and module id is stored)

permission table stores the info about the user permissions to particular modules

now I want to fetch the output from these 3 table which should look like the "output for sql query"

**User Table**
User ID | Name
1           | Charlie
2           | Mona

**Permission Table**
ID | User ID | Mudule ID
1  |  1           | 1
2  |1           | 2
3  | 2           | 1

**Module Table**
Module ID | Name
1               | Desktop PC
2               | Android
3               | IPhone

***Output for Query***
name    | permission 1 | permission 2 | permission n
Charlie  | Desktop PC   | Android
Mona   | Desktop PC

Comment: google *dynamic pivot sql server*

Comment: that is a rough view PK in permission table is just ID please consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT pvt.*
FROM ( 
    SELECT u.name as username, m.[Module Id], m.name as modulename
    FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN Permissions as p
            ON u.[User Id] = p.[User Id]
    INNER JOIN Modules as m
            ON p.[Module Id] = m.[Module Id]
) as data
PIVOT (
    MAX(data.modulename)
    FOR m.[Module Id] IN([1],[2])
) as pvt
```

You'll still need to adapt the table names and the columns to your real names. :-)

If you need a dynamic solution you may want to run this instead:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @columns nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + N',['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[module Id])+']',
                            N'['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[module Id])+']')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [module ID]
    FROM Modules
) as cols

SET @sql = N'
SELECT pvt.*
FROM ( 
    SELECT u.name as username, m.[Module Id], m.name as modulename
    FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN Permissions as p
            ON u.[User Id] = p.[User Id]
    INNER JOIN Modules as m
            ON p.[Module Id] = m.[Module Id]
) as data
PIVOT (
    MAX(data.modulename)
    FOR m.[Module Id] IN('+@columns+')
) as pvt'
EXEC(@sql)
```